# angular ng2 file upload issue

Tags: angular, angular5, multer, ng2-file-upload

I am trying to upload different documents. But the problem comes when i choose a file 2nd time it gets added to fileArray, it don't get replaced.

For example, i have choosen a picture for 1st input. Then i decided to choose different picture for the same input then it will get added to an array of files so when i will upload it, that previous picture will also be uploaded which i don't want to.

Is there any solution (other than using multiple files upload with single button ) so that when i choose a file 2nd time then it will get replaced instead of added to the files array ?

uploadDocument.html File :

```
<form (ngSubmit)=f.form.valid && formSubmit() #f="ngForm">

        <input type="file" class="form-control ml-2" name="photo" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
          <input type="file" class="form-control ml-2" name="document1" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
            <input type="file" class="form-control ml-2" name="pic2" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-fill">Upload</button>

</form>
```

uploadDocument.component.ts File :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../_services';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params} from '@angular/router';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
import { FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'http://localhost:3002/api/upload';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-uploadDocument',
    templateUrl: './uploadDocument.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./uploadDocument.component.scss']
})

export class UploadDocument implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    mobile: number;
    options: boolean;
    loading = false;
    public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router, private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {


        this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item)=> {console.log("Item"); console.log(item)};

        this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file)=> { file.withCredentials = false;};

       this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item:any, response:any, status:any, headers:any) => {
             console.log("ImageUpload:uploaded:", item, status, response);
        };
    }

    formSubmit() {
        this.uploader.uploadAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me first three inputs were required and other three inputs were optional so i did it this way and each input will always accept only 1 file and it will get replaced if another file is choosen:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiDomain } from '../url.constants';

const URL = ApiDomain+'/api/upload';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-uploadDocument',
    templateUrl: './uploadDocument.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./uploadDocument.component.scss']
})

export class UploadDocument implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    id: string;
    options: boolean;
    loading = false;
    files = [];
    flag: number = 0;
    formData: FormData;
    filesArray: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params: Params) => {
                this.id = params["id"];
                console.log(this.id);
            });

    }

    formSubmit() {
        this.loading = true;
        let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#tenththmarksheet');
        let inputEl1: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#photo');
        let inputEl2: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#aadharcard');
        let inputEl3: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#caste');
        let inputEl4: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#bhamasha');
        let inputEl5: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#moolnivas');


        let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
        let fileCount1: number = inputEl1.files.length;
        let fileCount2: number = inputEl2.files.length;
        let fileCount3: number = inputEl3.files.length;
        let fileCount4: number = inputEl4.files.length;
        let fileCount5: number = inputEl5.files.length;

        let formData = new FormData();

        if (fileCount > 0 && fileCount1 > 0 && fileCount2 > 0) {

            formData.append('id', this.id);
            formData.append('tenthmarksheet', inputEl.files.item(0));
            formData.append('photo', inputEl1.files.item(0));
            formData.append('aadhar', inputEl2.files.item(0));

            if (fileCount3 > 0) {
                formData.append('castecertificate', inputEl3.files.item(0));
            }
            if (fileCount4 > 0) {
                formData.append('bhamasha', inputEl4.files.item(0));
            }

            if (fileCount5 > 0) {
                formData.append('moolniwas', inputEl5.files.item(0));
            }

            this.http.post(URL, formData).subscribe(
                (complete) => {
                    this.loading = false;    
                    this.router.navigate(['/thankyou']);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even I lost couple of hours due to this. At last I done one tweak to fix it. Whenever a new file is uploaded, the uploaded queue is reset to store only the latest file only.This is done with the help of  `onAfterAddingFile` callback of the library provided function. Below is the changed code.

uploadDocument.component.ts File :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../_services';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params} from '@angular/router';
import { FileUploader, FileItem } from 'ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'http://localhost:3002/api/upload';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-uploadDocument',
    templateUrl: './uploadDocument.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./uploadDocument.component.scss']
})

export class UploadDocument implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    mobile: number;
    options: boolean;
    loading = false;
    public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router, private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {

         this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem: FileItem) => this.onAfterAddingFile(fileItem)

    }

    onAfterAddingFile(fileItem: FileItem) {
       let latestFile = this.uploader.queue[this.uploader.queue.length-1]
       this.uploader.queue = []; 
       this.uploader.queue.push(latestFile);
    }

    formSubmit() {
        this.uploader.uploadAll();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you!.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i believe it will work since you have tested, i also have found out the solution before that i will post in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can show the queue and let the user manage (delete) the files. Is not optimal but it works.

```
    <p class="files-uploaded" *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
      <strong>
        {{ item?.file?.name }} 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"(click)="item.remove()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
        </button>
      </strong>
    </p>
```